# Можно ли использовать html теги в БД?

Tags: android, html, sqlite

Есть база данных. Мне нужно использовать символы: `b, i, u, h2` и "пробел". Если выводить в `textview` из `string`, то нужно писать текст с тегами между `DATA`. А что делать в "БД", чтобы была поддержка `html` тегов? Экранировать?

Comment: БД, в общем-то, наплевать, что в ней хранится.

Comment: Т.е. если я в ячейке БД напишу: "<b> привет </b>" и выведу в textview, то слово "привет" будет выделено жирным, а не "<b>привет</b>"?

Comment: Это зависит не от БД. В БД просто хранятся данные. Формат вывода это уже ваше дело.

Comment: Не, ну вот например в string html не поддерживается, если не прописать в Java поддержку при выводе: html.fromhtml. , а сам текст с тегами не находится между: cdata. поэтому я про БД спрашиваю. Так cdata не подойдет, а значит и теги не поддерживаются.

Comment: Ещё раз. В БД хранится просто последовательность символов. Смысл и форму ей придаёт тот код, что занимается её выводом на экран: с предварительной обработкой, разбором или чем бы там ни было ещё.

Comment: Хорошо. Но если в string нужно помещать текст с тегами между cdata, иначе теги не работают - это факт. Пусть так как вы говорите, не спорю, но что делать с бд? Или как вывести на экран с бд, чтобы html теги работали?

Answer (score 1):

В базе данных необходимо экранировать только спец символы, в момент написания SQL запросов, такие например как апострофы, одиночные кавычки, обратные слеши.
Это нужно для того чтобы запрос к базе выполнился правильно, а не выполнился с ошибкой или например не уничтожил ваши данные в базе. В HTML могут присутствовать одиночные кавычки, апострофы и все что угодно на самом деле, поэтому экранировать придется рано или поздно.

Comment: А лучше использовать адаптеры для БД с поддержкой параметризованных запросов, в которых экранировать вручную ничего не надо.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы по нажатии на кнопку из БД вынималась определенная ячейка в textview. В ячейке БД будет находиться текст с html тегами. Так вот, что нужно экранировать? Я пишу текст с тегами  в БД как я бы это делал в string, а экранировать надо спецсимволы при запросе к бд?